# How can i make sure the image is not saved to gallery?

Tags: java, android, internal-storage

I'm making an app that will let users password-protect photos.  So far, the user can take a photo and the photo gets displayed.  However, all the photos get saved to camera roll.  How can I save them to the app instead of camera roll so they can be private, but still be able to access them from their uri (which I will save to SharedPreferences) ?

```
int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 0;
Uri imageUri;

public void takePic(View view){


Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
 imageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "filename_" +
        String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"));
intent.putExtra("data", imageUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);



}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {


        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

        Log.e("URI", imageUri.toString());
        Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);




    }
    else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Picture was not taken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
}


}
```

Comment: What is camera roll?

Comment: Then edit your post of course.

Answer (score 0):

create a file named (.nomedia) in the folder, then all the photos in this folder will not be shown!
OR
Save your photos on Internal storage.